# Print query error , connection error , result ok in php for my piece of code

Tags: php

PHP script invoke methods to connect db & execute query  :

https://3v4l.org/mS3ZZ

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 

   require_once 'db_connect_execute.php';
   if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
          {
           $rawdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
           $array=json_decode($rawdata, true);
           }
   $execution_id= $array['execution_id'];
   $rawDatas = $array['rawdata'][0];

   // Get all task_ids & respective raw json 

   foreach($rawDatas as $key =>$data) 
       {
    $task_id= $key;
    $flow = $data['flow'];
    $input= json_encode($data);

// Insert data in table garage_tasks

$sql = "INSERT INTO reporting_queued_tasks (execution_id,task_id,flow,client_input_data,status)VALUES('$execution_id','$key','$flow','$input','QUEUED')";
$result= new db (); 
$result-> execute_query ($sql);

}

?>
```

PHP script to connect db & execute it :

https://3v4l.org/D6FrR

```
<?php

class Db {

protected static $connection;

public function connect() {    
       //To create DB connection & validate connection 
        if(!isset($connection)) 
        {

            $config = parse_ini_file('./config.ini'); 
            $connection = new mysqli( $config['servername'],$config['username'],$config['password'],$config['database']);
        }

        if($connection ->connect_error) {

        echo ($connection->connect_error);
        die("could not connect");

            return false;
        }
        echo "Return OK";
        echo "\r\n";
        return $connection;
    }

public function execute_query($query) {
        // Connect to the database
        $connection = $this -> connect();

        // Query the database
        $result = $connection -> query($query);
        return $result;
    }



}   
?>
```

Problem statement :

I need to get mysql connection error , query error & if everything goes well should say Return OK ( my present code print repetitive return Ok I need once )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the DB connection file to

```
<?php
class Db {
    protected static $connection;
    public function Db() {    
        //To create DB connection & validate connection         
        if(!isset($connection)) 
        {
            $config = parse_ini_file('./config.ini'); 
            Db::$connection = new mysqli( $config['servername'],$config['username'],$config['password'],$config['database']);
        }

        if(Db::$connection ->connect_error) {
            echo (Db::$connection->connect_error);
            die("could not connect");
            return false;
        }else{      
            echo "Return OK";
            echo "\r\n";
            return Db::$connection;
        }
    }
//Do not call connection method every time you call execute_query 
// So moved it to the class constructor
//Use the $connection variable to execute query
    public function execute_query($query) {     
        // Query the database
        $result = Db::$connection->query($query);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

When you create the Db class object the connection will be created automatically and use can run the query like this:

```
$ob = new Db;
$query = 'Your query';
$ob->execute_query($query);
```